# Vectorizing MNIST KNN in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization, knn, mnist

I'm working with MNIST data set 60000 points each of 784 pixels. I have a test set that is 10000 points and of course same number of pixels.

I'm trying to figure out what is the most efficient way in Matlab (besides just using built-in fit functions) to determine KNN for K=1 over this test set. I am looping through each test point sequentially then calculating the distances from that particular digit to all other digits in one function (`pdist2`), but that still seems to not be fast enough. Doing this takes about 3 seconds just to get through 10 data points. So how can I vectorize even the looping through digits part?

For example, trying to get rid of this loop:

```
[testRows, ~] = size(X_test);
for r=1:testRows  
    digit = X_test(r,:);
    distance = pdist2(digit,X_train,'euclidean');

end
```

Comment: Have you tried [dsearchn](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dsearchn.html)?

Comment: After all is it python or matlab? The text, title, code, tag are not consistent.

Comment: Oops sorry I don't know why I wrote python in the title I meant Matlab. I think this `dsearchn` function may be what I'm looking for I'm going to play around with it for a bit.